# Usage history of Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I work with legacy systems that have tens of thousand of lines of stored procedure code, where many of the stored procedures are obsolete and not used anymore. There doesn't seem to be a way to check execution history, so my question is if it might be a good idea to start each stored procedure by inserting a row into a table that keeps records of the execution?

could be very simple like:

insert into
    executionHistory (
        name,
        date
    )
    select
        'spName',
        getdate()

-- then rest of procedure

I imagine this could be very useful for doing cleanups of old unused code, and might also be handy when trying to decide where to optimize. I mean it's better to shave 10 seconds off execution time on a procedure that is executed 50 times a day, than saving 10 minutes execution time on a procedure that is only used once a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea is simple enough and would accomplish your goal. Though it would involve modifying every SP, it's the route I would choose. Then you can ensure that you're getting an accurate recording of all activity on the database.

Another poster suggested you do a trace - while this works for short periods, it's only going to catch the time you're watching. You'd have to make sure you traces across any important, high-traffic periods, like month-end financial closing, and even then, you're missing other times you don't think are that big a deal, so you're being subjective.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the case, usage usually peaks after turn of month, turn of quarter, turn of year.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tracing option (SQL Profiler) in SQL server. you could take a trace of a days SQL activity and see which sprocs are executed there.

This will give you a good idea of where to focus your optimisations.

Answer (score 1):

because you're using sql server 2008 i wouldn't do what rwmnau suggest because this would mean you have to modify all your stored procedures.
SQL Server 2008 introduces a feature called Extended Events and SQL Server Auditing based on them. Extended events are high performance tracing system.
by using SQL Server Auditing you can trace your system withouth the overhead of sql trace.